# Angularjs ui-select Dynamic object mapping inside repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, ui-select

my ui-select directive code is below just working fine. Inside repeat , i need to set propert of **CODE** object (which is ID) to dynamic like **code[fwValueProperty]**. As far as i know  , it is not ng-repeat so i cannot use it as code[fwValueProperty]. How can i achieve this?

```
<div>
    <ui-select name="{{fwName}}"
               id="{{fwId}}"
               theme="bootstrap"
               ng-model="fwValue"
               reset-search-input="false"
               append-to-body="true"
               search-enabled="true"
               on-select="onSelected(fwValue)">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Seçiniz..."><span ng-bind="$select.selected[fwDescriptionProperty]"></span> </ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="code.ID as code in fwCodes  | propsFilter: { '{{fwDescriptionProperty}}': $select.search} track by $index"
                           refresh-delay="0">
            <div ng-bind-html="code[fwDescriptionProperty] | highlight: $select.search"></div> <!--fwDescriptionProperty , descriptionProp(item)-->
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i did mistyped somewhere. Now it works as it should be:

```
 <ui-select-choices repeat="code[fwValueProperty] as code in fwCodes  | propsFilter: { '{{fwDescriptionProperty}}': $select.search} track by $index"
                           refresh-delay="0">
```

Comment: dynamic ng-select on click of a button not working for me